# filter property of object with diferent options

Tags: javascript

I need to get the values of prices of the options with amount > 0. I solve this by creating two variables.  The reduce method is flatting the array, my question is: It's a way to make this with no need of flat the array? I think i'm making a two dimensional array and then flatting. Thanks in advance

```js
let burger = {
    name: 'burger stack',
    price: 8,
    variants: [
        {
            name: 'sauce',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'ketchup',
                    price: 2,
                    amount: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'mayo',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'extra',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'meat',
                    price: 3,
                    amount: 2
                },
                {
                    name: 'cheese',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}



let filtered = burger.variants.map(x => x.options.filter(y => y.amount > 0 ? y.price : 0)).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
console.log(filtered)

let prices = filtered.map(x => x.price * x.amount)
console.log(prices)
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? `let filtered = burger.variants.map(x => x.options.filter(y => y.amount > 0 ? y.price : 0)).flat(2).map(x => x.price * x.amount)`? You can chain the functions.

Comment: You already have a function, which is hard to read. For maintainability reasons, I wouldn't recommend shorten it's even more. That's the job of the compressor

Comment: good point, i'm wondering if it's possible to make this with no need of flat(2). thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can chain few Array methods like `flatMap()`, `filter()` and finally `map()` :

```js
let burger = {
  name: 'burger stack',
  price: 8,
  variants: [
      {
          name: 'sauce',
          options: [
              {
                  name: 'ketchup',
                  price: 2,
                  amount: 1
              },
              {
                  name: 'mayo',
                  price: 1,
                  amount: 0
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: 'extra',
          options: [
              {
                  name: 'meat',
                  price: 3,
                  amount: 2
              },
              {
                  name: 'cheese',
                  price: 1,
                  amount: 0
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}

const res = burger.variants.flatMap(({ options }) => 
            options.filter(({ amount }) => 
            amount)).map(({ price, amount }) => price * amount);

console.log(res);
```

For readability issue, it's better to separate to 2 lines or more, step by step, rather than create it in 1 line that could be very long and confusing to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let burger = {
    name: 'burger stack',
    price: 8,
    variants: [
        {
            name: 'sauce',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'ketchup',
                    price: 2,
                    amount: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'mayo',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'extra',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'meat',
                    price: 3,
                    amount: 2
                },
                {
                    name: 'cheese',
                    price: 1,
                    amount: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

 
let filtered = burger.variants.map(x => x.options.filter(y => y.amount > 0 ? y.price : 0)).flat(2).map(x => x.price * x.amount)

console.log(filtered)
```